# Mutation of a binary vector inside a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, genetic-algorithm, mutation

```
import random 

chosen=[[[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [3], [0]], 
        [[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [5], [2]]]    

def mutation(chosen, mp):
    for i in range(len(chosen)):
        if random.random() < mp:
            chosen[0][i] = type(chosen[0][i])(not chosen[0][i])
    return (chosen)

mp=0.9 #probability
mutated=mutation(chosen, mp)
print (mutated)
```

Assuming that `chosen` stands for the selected individuals in a population, I am trying to mutate the binary vectors (at random position) based on the given probability. and return it in a different list (I am still not sure if the extra list is necessary).

It's not really working as expected, anyone knows what could be wrong in the code?

```
  File "<ipython-input-229-91852a46fa82>", line 9, in mutation
    chosen[0][i] = type(chosen[0][i])(not chosen[0][i])

TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable
```

Also, if someone knows a more convenient way for this it would be totally welcome.

Thank you!

Comment: "not really working as expected" is pretty vague.  Show an example of calling the function, what the expected output is, and what the actual output is, along with the full traceback of any error messages.  Make a standalone program that we can cut-n-paste into a script and run.

Comment: Ive made it an standalone program andadded the output to the question, thanks!

Comment: 81% of the time, that is the correct output for what you've written.  What do you expect?

Comment: ...(assuming `import random` and `mp=.1` are added to the script...not very standalone :^)

Comment: You are totally right, actually I had the wrong approach to the program, I see now that there is no point in creating a second list

Comment: What are those single-item lists? How are they related to the problem? What would be the expected output for the given list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still guessing at what you want, but if you just want to flip one of the binary bits:

```
import random

chosen=[[[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [3], [0]], 
        [[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [5], [2]]]    

def mutation(chosen, mp):
    for i in range(len(chosen)):
        if random.random() < mp:
            pos = random.randrange(len(chosen[i][0]))
            chosen[i][0][pos] = 0 if chosen[i][0][pos] else 1

# before
for item in chosen:
    print(item)
print()

mutation(chosen, 1) # 100% of the time, for now

# after
for item in chosen:
    print(item)
```

Output (note last bit changed and 3rd bit changed in the rows):

```
[[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [3], [0]]
[[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [5], [2]]

[[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [3], [0]]
[[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [5], [2]]
```